# When item modified with trigger condition it should trigger email

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, power-automate, flow, power-platform

[image]

I have set below Trigger condition when item create or modified

```
@and(equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/SRVolunteer/Value'],'Yes'),equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/SRroles/Value'],null))
```

Issue: It is showing below error:

[image]

Comment: What is the column/data type of SRroles and SRVolunteer columns? When you see this error, while saving flow or while running it?

Comment: SRroles is choice field(Dropdown) and SRVolunteer is single line of text.I got above error when i try to run the flow

Comment: Expanding on Ganesh's comment, change your Single line of text from ['body/SRVolunteer/Value'] to just ['body/SRVolunteer']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `SRVolunteer` is a single line of text column, you don't have to use `/Value` in expression for this column.

Use below expression for trigger condition:

```
@and(equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/SRVolunteer'],'Yes'),equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/SRroles/Value'],null))
```

**OR** try using this expression:

```
@and(equals(triggerBody()?['SRVolunteer'],'Yes'),equals(triggerBody()?['SRroles/Value'],null))
```